# Solana showing wrong timestamp for Testnet Transactions

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli

I was developing my **crypto-based project** using the **Solana blockchain**. I did all the operations using Solana's **Devnet** < Solana Developer Network >. Recently I switched to **Solana Testnet** and when I try to fetch details of the transaction signature using their API or solscan.io, It is showing a **wrong timestamp** < 7 days ago, 14 days ago, etc.. > for the transaction.

Any idea about this? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Testnet cluster was down for an extended period of time, from Nov 2 to Nov 18. Due to this downtime, the cluster time fell behind wallclock time.

This is known / expected behavior when there is extended downtime; however, Testnet's time it already catching and will fully catchup eventually.